# All elements in list getting set to latest item's value

Tags: kotlin

Needing help with this the below Kotlin code.
I am working on a bigger project where I faced this problem and have created a smaller example,

```
data class EachDay(var day: String, var todo: String)
{

}

data class Week(val list:MutableList<EachDay>)
{

}

fun main() {
    val eachDay = EachDay(day="", todo="")
    var week:Week = Week(arrayListOf<EachDay>())

    eachDay.day="Saturday"
    eachDay.todo="Shopping, Groceries"
    week.list.add(eachDay)
    println("Week" +week)
    eachDay.day="Sunday"
    eachDay.todo="Rest"
    week.list.add(eachDay)
    println("Week" +week)
    eachDay.day="Monday"
    eachDay.todo="Check emails, resume work"
    week.list.add(eachDay)
    println("Week" +week)
}
```

On running we get:

```
WeekWeek(list=[EachDay(day=Saturday, todo=Shopping, Groceries)])
WeekWeek(list=[EachDay(day=Sunday, todo=Rest), EachDay(day=Sunday, todo=Rest)])
WeekWeek(list=[EachDay(day=Monday, todo=Check emails, resume work), EachDay(day=Monday, todo=Check emails, resume work), EachDay(day=Monday, todo=Check emails, resume work)])
```

Have tried variations of above code in many ways just to get the same problem of repeating elements
Originally I did not have a data class for list of Items, just declaring it as list of items, so instead of week.list.add it would be week.add, but still with same problem
Why are all the elements getting set to same value as element. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: You keep adding the same instance `eachDay` to your list. You only ever created one instance, and you're just modifying the existing instance when you change the values of `day` and `todo`. Assuming you're new to object-oriented programming...the first thing you need to learn after learning how to work with numbers and Strings is what an object instance is and what references are.

Comment: Hasn't this issue cropped up quite a few times? A quick search doesn't show up any duplicates, but I'm sure I've seen some…

Comment: @gidds I did not even know how to frame my question in words, I have searched with search strings like "all elements get set to latest item value" and other variations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either create a new `EachDay` object or copy it and setting the new values otherwise you will be applying the changes to the same `EachDay` object.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var week:Week = Week(arrayListOf<EachDay>())

    week.list.add(EachDay(day="Saturday", todo="Shopping, Groceries"))
    println("Week" +week)
    week.list.add(EachDay(day="Sunday", todo="Rest"))
    println("Week" +week)
    week.list.add(EachDay(day="Monday", todo="Check emails, resume work"))
    println("Week" +week)
}
```

Or

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val eachDay = EachDay(day="", todo="")
    var week:Week = Week(arrayListOf<EachDay>())

    week.list.add(eachDay.copy(day="Saturday", todo="Shopping, Groceries"))
    println("Week" +week)
    week.list.add(eachDay.copy(day="Sunday", todo="Rest"))
    println("Week" +week)
    week.list.add(eachDay.copy(day="Monday", todo="Check emails, resume work"))
    println("Week" +week)
}
```

I would go with the first one.